# How do i create dynamic confirm dialog in jsf

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces

I need a dynamic confirm dialog. When I press command button it must show. I used JOptionPane. it almost OK. But It not append to body. It separate from parent window.  When I change window, it covered by another windows. So i need create confirm dialog. I do not know how to create it dynamically. I am using jsf, primefaces 4.0 Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrimeFaces provides variety of UI components and it has got a good list [showcased](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase.xhtml) here

To pop-up a confirm dialog on click of command button, you can go for `<p:confirmDialog>` , simply as

```
<h:form>          
<p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />

<p:commandButton value="Destroy the World" 
                 actionListener="#{dialogView.destroyWorld}" update="message">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" 
               message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" 
                     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" 
                     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

Will pop-up a `confirm dialog` on click of button